# Installing Symfony on Mac OS X

Tags: symfony

I am having trouble installing this framework.

I entered this command on terminal as per the instructions on http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html. This was from the desktop.

```
$ php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony.phar
```

The next part requires me to add this code:

```
$ sudo mv symfony.phar /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

Now I get this error:

```
mv: rename symfony.phar to /usr/local/bin/symfony: Not a directory
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: I am having same problem. Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try and move it to `/usr/bin` instead.

The directory you're trying to move it to doesn't exist. The instructions you're following may not be intended for OS X users.

The executable can go anywhere that's in your `PATH`.

Comment: it was intended for OS X users. I added a link

Comment: Did my suggestion work? You can put it anywhere that's in your path basically though.